# QGIS Print composer bitmaps everything

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have been exporting maps as PDFs for some time now, and now, all of a sudden, the Printcomposer "converts" everything (except the North arrow and the scale bar) to a single bitmap, including the grid and grid labels, but also shape layers that contain polygons. It also "removes" the Frame of the Grid that I added.

I have tried to export some older maps with Layouts that I made earlier, but they now also produce a single bitmap when exported as a PDF.

As far as I know, I did not change any settings. Is there a way to revert this behaviour?
I am using QGIS 3.8.2, all maps were created today, but at some point, something changed.

Attached are some screenshots:

The original Map with the zebra frame and grid labels als text objects:
[image: The original Map with the zebra frame and grid labels als text objects]

The erronous Map from the same Layout, without the zebra frame and grid labels as well as everything else (exept North Arrow and Scalebar) in a single bitmap. Also note the labels of my point layer, which are also now pixelated and not text objects:
[image: The erronous Map from the same Layout, without the zebra frame and grid labels as well as everything else (exept North Arrow and Scalebar) in a single bitmap]

Comment: Did you updated QGIS recently ? Can you update the QGIS version to the last version or last LTR version or do you have to stick with the 3.8 ?

Comment: I did not update QGIS. As I said, this all happened today, 2 hours ago it was working as usual.

Comment: Did you add any layers with blending modes for the whole layer (e.g. Screen, Multiply, Overlay etc.) Earlier versions of QGIS were completely unable to export these effects except if they flattened the whole map to a raster. Normally a message would pop up warning you of this but it's possible to have accidentally permanently hidden the message. Later versions you are able to export the PDF as a GeoPDF (if the map is not rotated and an atlas is not used...) which lets you have layers with blending modes enabled. I also assume you haven't accidentally checked 'Print as raster' anywhere